# TORQUE- qsub: job gets rejected if there are not enough number of nodes

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

When I submit a job using `qsub` job gets rejected if not enough nodes available. Is there any config that says to QUEUE(without running) the job instead of rejecting.

Comment: Probably something wrong with the job specification. Rejection usually means the nodes required are not available at all. If they were busy, the job would have stayed in the queue.

Comment: Yes.. job gets rejected when not enough nodes available(I mentioned that..) I found something called qmgr : set queue queue_name resources_available.nodect=nodes. Where 'nodes' is number greater than physically available nodes. This way I could make the job to get submitted and be in queued state

Comment: To rephrase what @DmitriChubarov is saying pbs doesn't reject jobs because not enough nodes are currently available, it rejects jobs when the requested resources can never be available. For example, if you request 100 nodes but your system only has 90, this will be rejected. If you request 50 nodes but only 40 are free, the job will be queued.